# Execute .cpp file from processBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

How can I execute C++ code from JAVA, I am now executing .exe file from processBuilder, but I want to execute it from code. Can any one know how can i do that?

Comment: You need to compile it.

Comment: My guess is you'd have to use process builder to compile it into an exe, and then use process builder again to run the exe.  Also, you should be aware of JNI.

Comment: C++ code won't run inside a JVM.  You have to run it as an executable.

Comment: @tieTYT can i compile it using ProcessBuilder?

Comment: @UsamaNadeem yes, use process builder to run the compile command.

Comment: Of course if you did that, you would have to deal sensibly with compilation errors. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to compile the file into executable code, first. A *cpp* file by itself is not executable since C++ is not an interpreted language. However, you could try using an interpreter for C++ such as [cint](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint) or [igcc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/igcc/) which compiles the C++ code on the fly. For this, you would call the interpreter directly from Java and supply the C++ file as an addtional argument to the interpreter of your choice. I personally never tried this. though.

In most cases, it makes however more sence to supply compiled code.